# Entity Framework 6 transaction rollback

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

With EF6 you have a new transaction which can be used like:

```
using (var context = new PostEntityContainer())
        {
            using (var dbcxtransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    PostInformation NewPost = new PostInformation()
                    {
                        PostId = 101,
                        Content = "This is my first Post related to Entity Model",
                        Title = "Transaction in EF 6 beta"
                    };
                    context.Post_Details.Add(NewPost);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    PostAdditionalInformation PostInformation = new PostAdditionalInformation()
                    {
                        PostId = (101),
                        PostName = "Working With Transaction in Entity Model 6 Beta Version"
                    };

                    context.PostAddtional_Details.Add(PostInformation);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    dbcxtransaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    dbcxtransaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
```

Is rollback actually needed when things go sideways? I'm curious because the Commit description says: "Commits the underlying store transaction."

Whereas the Rollback description says: "Rolls back the underlying store transaction."

This makes me curious, because it looks to me that if Commit isn't called, the previously executed commands will not be stored (which seems logical to me). But if that is the case, what would the reason be to call the Rollback function? In EF5 I used TransactionScope which didn't have a Rollback function (only a Complete) which seemed logical to me. Due to MS DTC reasons I cannot use the TransactionScope anymore, but I also cannot use a try catch like the example above (i.e., I only need the Commit).

Comment: Have you read-up on [transactions in sql](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions)? EF tries to mimic that. AFAIK, if you don't commit a transaction in sql, it is rolled back.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4896479/1043380).

Comment: Yes, I know about transactions in SQL itself. I was curious what EF does, but if they mimic that, it makes sense. I'll see if I can work around it. Thank you!

Comment: SaveChanges() always happens in a transaction which will be rolled back if an exception happens. In your case there is no need to try to handle this manually (in this particular case it would be even better to add all entities first and `SaveChanges` only once).

Comment: I only want items to be saved from both SaveChanges when both don't fail, so yes, I do need a single transaction around the both of them.

Comment: SaveChanges() will only be rolled back for a entity throwing exception. If you are updating multiple entities, you should use Transaction to rollback back entire process as a part of atomic process.

Comment: @Areius I know this is an old question, but I'm curious why you said you couldn't use a try catch block. I can't think of a single reason why anyone would not be able to do that. (unless you're wanting to catch the exception at another point and didn't realize that you could just throw from the catch block)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You don't need to call `Rollback` manually because you are using the `using` statement.

`DbContextTransaction.Dispose` method will be called at the end of the `using` block. And it will automatically rollback the transaction if the transaction is not successfully committed (not called or encountered exceptions). Following is the source code of `SqlInternalTransaction.Dispose` method (`DbContextTransaction.Dispose` will finally delegate to it when using SqlServer provider):

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // ...
    if (disposing && this._innerConnection != null)
    {
        this._disposing = true;
        this.Rollback();
    }
}
```

You see, it checks if `_innerConnection` is not null, if not, rollback the transaction (if committed, `_innerConnection` will be null). Let's see what `Commit` does:

```
internal void Commit() 
{
    // Ignore many details here...
    
    this._innerConnection.ExecuteTransaction(...);

    if (!this.IsZombied && !this._innerConnection.IsYukonOrNewer)
    {
        // Zombie() method will set _innerConnection to null
        this.Zombie();
    }
    else
    {
        this.ZombieParent();
    }

    // Ignore many details here...
}

internal void Zombie()
{
    this.ZombieParent();

    SqlInternalConnection innerConnection = this._innerConnection;

    // Set the _innerConnection to null
    this._innerConnection = null;

    if (innerConnection != null)
    {
        innerConnection.DisconnectTransaction(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

As long as you will always be using SQL Server with EF, there is no need to explicitly use the catch to call the Rollback method.  Allowing the using block to automatically rollback on any exceptions will always work.

However, when you think about it from the Entity Framework point of view, you can see why all examples use the explicit call to Rollback the transaction.  To the EF, the database provider is arbitrary and pluggable and the provider can be replaced with MySQL or any other database that has an EF provider implementation.  Therefore, from the EF point of view, there is no guarantee that the provider will automatically rollback the disposed transaction, because the EF does not know about the implementation of the database provider.

So, as a best practice, the EF documentation recommends that you explicitly Rollback -- just in case you someday change providers to an implementation that does not auto-rollback on dispose.

In my opinion, any good and well written provider will automatically rollback the transaction in the dispose, so the additional effort to wrap everything inside the using block with a try-catch-rollback is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. I dove into the code and you end up at the abstract class DbTransaction's Dispose which is overridden in SqlTransaction which itself calls the SqlInternalTransaction mentioned by Mouhong Lin.

Answer (score 5):

1. Since you have written a 'using' block to instantiate the
   transaction, you do not need to mention the Rollback function
   explicitly since it would be automatically rolled back (unless it was
   committed) at the time of disposal.
2. But if you instantiate it without a using block, in that case it is
   essential to rollback the transaction in case of an exception (precisely in
   a catch block) and that too with a null check for a more
   robust code. The working of BeginTransaction is unlike transaction
   scope (which just needs a complete function if all the operations
   were completed successfully). Instead, it is akin to the working of
   Sql transactions.