# Value cannot be null: connection while testing database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to run integration tests for my ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework 6.

The error I get is

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Rollback. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connection

The code looks like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new PrimaryInitializerTest());
_context = new PrimaryContextTest();
_context.Database.Initialize(true);

using (var dbt = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
     dbt.Commit();
     dbt.Rollback();
}
```

I also tried having an `dbt.UnderlyingTransaction.Connection.Open()` call just below the using statement, and a `dbt.UnderlyingTransaction.Connection.Close()` call just below the call to `Rollback()`. That gave me the error `Connection is not closed`.

`PrimaryInitializerTest` class

```
protected override void Seed(PrimaryContextTest context)
{
    // (...) Input some values
    base.Seed(context);
}
```

`PrimaryContextTest` class

```
public class PrimaryContextTest : DbContext
{
    public PrimaryContextTest() : base("PrimaryContextTest")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PrimaryContextTest>());
    }

    public DbSet<Story> Stories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
    }
}
```

Connection string

```
<add name="PrimaryContextTest" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=PrimaryContextTest;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PrimaryContextTest.mdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Context string

```
<context type="fcon.DAL.Tests.PrimaryContextTest, fcon, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
    <databaseInitializer type="fcon.DAL.Tests.PrimaryInitializerTest, fcon" />
</context>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Might mention that the database doesn't exist in the `App_Data` folder...

Comment: When exactly does the error happen? When you start the app?

Comment: When I run the test, and the program executes the Rollback function. Here are the variables if it helps http://i.imgur.com/ObGGgww.png

Comment: Though I'm not sure why you're getting a null reference exception, it doesn't really make sense to `Commit` and then immediately `Rollback` a transaction. It's definitely an error (SQL Server will also throw an error), though it shouldn't be a null error.

Comment: I'm new to working with Entity like this. Are the changes in context.Save() method actually saved? I thought they were just cached somehow.

Comment: Because when I just call Rollback() I don't see the Database variable change. I don't see it reverting the item I added to the database.

Comment: Well of course not. Once you committed the transaction, that's it, there's no transaction anymore to roll back.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I am getting this error when the Commit call fails.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486489/entity-framework-6-transaction-rollback

Comment: This error is caused generally due to some other failure!

Answer (score 8):

You're calling `Commit` and then `Rollback`, but the comments point that mistake out.

The error isn't very intuitive, I mean, an `ArgumentNullException` should never work its way out of an SDK from down the stack.

But I've had this when I've accidentally reused the same transaction instance, or called `Commit` twice, or tried to rollback twice in layered error recovery logic.