# Why doesn't WebAPI2 with Entity Framework automatically create a transaction for me?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI2 Restful services API and I am using SQL Server database with Entity Framework. I have `PUT` methods like this

```
    /* 
     * This changes the Study Status.
     */
    [HttpPut, Route("ResponseSetStatus/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateResponseSetStatus(int id, [FromUri] string status = null)
    {
        var db = new MyContext(MyContext.EntityContextString);
        var responseSet = db.ResponseSets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResponseSetId == id);

        if (responseSet == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        // ADD ONE SECOND DELAY HERE FOR TESTING
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        responseSet.Status = status;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
```

I **thought** this would work! But it fails. One of the columns in the database is a `rowVersion` (to prevent lost updates). When I call this function from multiple clients I get exception...

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

because of `rowVersion` mismatch.  Do I **really** need an explicit transaction for all my update apis? I thought the framework is supposed to do that for me.

Comment: hmm, just noticed that the error contains a link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 telling me to catch the exception and try again -- in a loop! OMG

Comment: This is not sql-server related question, please use tags properly.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with transactions. EF does create a transaction for you when you SaveChanges(). You pull the data from the database in the meantime someone updates database and then you try to save your data on top of someone else changes. Because you are using rowVersion an exception is thrown so that you don't corrupt data. EF can't create a single transaction for your reads and writes since it would prevent everyone from using the db after you start reading and you may never have a write so you would block the database until the connection is closed. Reads don't need trx

Comment: Throwing `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is the expected behavior if you choose an Optimistic Concurrency approach. There is nothing wrong in your code. More info here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @Pawel, actually it is a good idea to wrap read and write in a single transaction. That is what transactions were made for. A relational database uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control which means that a transaction does not "block the database". If it does, you need to upgrade your database software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered, I will. Yes, WebAPI2 does **not** wrap the call in a transaction. That would be silly, if you think about it. Also the code

```
using (var db = new MyContext()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

does **not** implicitly create a transaction. Therefore, when you implement a RESTFUL PUT method to update your database, you have three options: (1) call `db.SaveChanges()` [one time only and hope for the best](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/821439/Getting-started-with-ASP-Net-Web-API-using-CodeF), as the OP code, or (2) you can add a rowVersion column, and call `db.SaveChanges()` with [try-catch in a loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx), or (3) you can [create an explicit transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx).

In my opinion, option 1 is evil, and option 2 is a terrible hack that was invented because transactions did not exist prior to EF6.

**The *correct* way to implement Update:**

```
[HttpPut, Route("ResponseSetStatus/{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateResponseSetStatus(int id, [FromUri] string status = null)
{
    using (var db = new MyContext(MyContext.EntityContextString))
    {
        using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
        { 
            var responseSet = db.ResponseSets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResponseSetId == id);

            if (responseSet == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // ADD ONE SECOND DELAY HERE FOR TESTING
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            responseSet.Status = status;
            tran.Commit();
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Please note that try-catch is not necessary. If anything fails, the `using tran` will [automatically rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486489/entity-framework-6-transaction-rollback), and the WebAPI2 will send a nice 500 response to the client.

p.s. i put the `db = new MyContext` also in using, because it's the right way to do it.