# How to roll back queries in C#?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I have list of delete queries & I execute them with this code:

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
{
    foreach (var item in queries)
    {
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item);
    }
}
```

I want to commit all the delete queries, but I want to roll back if there is some error in any of the queries.

How to do roll back in the above scenario?

Comment: Related/possible dup: [Entity Framework 6 transaction rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486489/entity-framework-6-transaction-rollback)

Comment: The keyword you may be looking for is "Transaction". I've linked a potential question that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use TransactionScope

```
using System.Transactions;

try
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
        {
            foreach (var item in queries)
            {
                ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item);
            }
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Got the compiler error - `'System.Activities.Statements.TransactionScope': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'`

Comment: Use TransactionScope from System.Transactions namespace:

Comment: Is it necessary to `Dispose` the Object in Catch statement if there is error?

Comment: @Anup It isn't necessary to call **Dispose** in **catch** or **finally** block. When program goes out of **using** it invokes **Dispose**