# Single ScopeTransaction with multiple DbContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, rollback

I have searched a lot on the Internet without finding similar case. I have one `TransactionScope` with several `DbContext`.

I want to commit changes to the database **only in case all context have saved changes successfully**.

But the problem I'm facing is that I had to call `generalContext.SaveChanges` in the middle of the code as the changes took place on data was retrieved by generalContext sometime earlier, but I noticed the changes are **committed right away** after calling `generalContext.SaveChanges()`.

What problem did I do?

I have tried `TransactionScopeOption.Required` and `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`, without being able to solve the problem

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
using (var generalContext = new CoreEntities())
{
    try
    {

        using (var subContext = new CoreEntities())
        {
            // the problem is here, that the changes are committed!!!
            generalContext.SaveChanges();


            subContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
    catch
    {
        scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: _[With the Entity Framework most of the time SaveChanges() is sufficient. This creates a transaction, or enlists in any ambient transaction, and does all the necessary work in that transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/815660/585968)_.   It's slightly different to your case; refers to an older version of EF; but it explains somethings.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/23308945/585968

Comment: Also, [Entity Framework Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @MickyD, but so far, still not working, if anyone can point out the problem here. Does the way of code-writing have any shortcomings which could've caused the issue at the first place?